# How Can I get Item by Attribute in DynamoDB in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have 7 columns,

```
id, firstname, lastname, email, phone, createAt, updatedAt
```

I am trying to write an api in Nodejs to get items by `phone`.

`id` is the primary key.

I am trying to get the data by phone or email. I didn't created sortkey or GSI yet.

I ended up getting suggestions to use `scan` with filters in dynamodb and get all records .

Is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question already contains two good answers:

1. The slow way is to use a `Scan` with a `FilterExpression` to find the matching items. This will take the time (and also cost!) of reading the entire database on every query. It only makes sense if these queries are very infrequent.
2. If these queries by `phone` are not super-rare, it is better to be prepared in advance: add a GSI with the `phone` as its partition key, to allow looking up items by phone value using a `Query` with `IndexName` and `KeyConditionExpression`. These queries will be fast and cheap: you will only pay for items actually retrieved. The downside of this approach is the increased write costs: The cost
   of every write doubles (DynamoDB writes to both the base table and
   the index), and the cost of storage increases as well. But unless
   your workload is write-mostly (items are very frequently updated and
   very rarely read), option 2, using a GSI, is still better than
   option 1 - a full-table `Scan`.

Finally another option you have is to reconsider your data model. For example, if you always look up items by `phone` and never by `id`, you can make `phone` the partition key of your data and `id` the sort key (to allow multiple items with the same `phone`). But I don't know if this is relevant for your use case. If you need to look up items sometimes by `id` and sometimes by `phone`, probably GSI is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks Nadav Har'EI, that was brillient. I would rather go with making phone as primary key to avoid GSI Costs. Thanks Alot